# asp.net breadcrumb

Tags: asp.net

What I want to do is a simple breadcrumb which I have accomplish this with Web.sitemap

Home--> page1 --> page2

**What I need to do**

If I navigate to *page1.aspx?param=value* and after this I go to *page2.aspx*
the breadcrumb  shows Home--> page1 --> page2 in which, if I click *Page1* it redirects me to page1.aspx but how could I retrieve the given variables from page1.aspx, so to be redirected to *page1.aspx?param=value*?

Thanks

Comment: The simplest thing would be to create your own breadcrumb control. This way you can send your parameters around and append them to the breadcrumb links.

Comment: Yes sure, but I am wondering if this can be accomplished with a .net control, somehow. If not then I'll do my own

Comment: Agree with klausbyskov - I found it lot simpler to have my own bread crumb implementation to get exactly what I want. In sitemap, you need to modify site nodes (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178425.aspx) - it entails creating custom control if you have to do that on all pages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will solve your specific issue but you should check out the MVC SiteMap Project on CodePlex, as a really good starting point:

http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/

You can avail of the new NuPack for an easy install of this:

http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/10/08/Using-MvcSiteMapProvider-throuh-NuPack.aspx

Comment: I'll check it out. If I can't use it for a web form site, I will use it for an MVC site.  Thanks IrishChieftain